# Enable non-admin remote access to IIS Manager

Tags: iis, remote-access, iis-8.5

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.  I've configured it for remote management, and I am able to successfully connect to the IIS mangement service (on this server) from another computer, as long as I login with an "admin" account (an acct that's in the local Administrators group on the server).

I've tried to enable IIS Manager to allow non-admin accounts:

1. I've enabled the remote Management Service:
   [image: Mgmt Service]
2. I've added some non-admin users:
   [image: Permissions]

But, the non-admin users cannot connect to the IIS remote mgmt service:
[image: Unauthorized]

As soon as I switch to an acct which is an admin on that server, it works:
[image: Authorized]

How can I get IIS to allow non-admins to connect to the remote management service?

**UPDATE:** Based on the answer given below, non-server-admins need to choose the IIS Manager option "Connect to a Site", not "Connect to a Server".  When you choose that option, you'll need to specify the Server name and the Site name:

[image: site]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-admins can connect to a web site. But only administrators can connect to the server. [Reference Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732466(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to "Connect to a Server", instead of "Connect to a Site".